# No write permission to drive (even as root) on dual-boot system

Tags: linux-mint, dual-boot, ntfs

I'm running a dual-boot setup with Windows 10 and Linux Mint 20.2 Cinnamon and encountered the problem that when I'm booted into Linux, I can mount and read drives without problem, but I can't write to them. This problem persists even as root and no matter the mount options.

Comment: This is a well-known problem, did you search Unix for former solutions? Because if there is, it will be marked as off-topic directed to SuperUser, or duplicate.

Comment: Yes, I searched quite a while online, tried a ton of different stuff but nothing worked. I never found this solution online. I got it from my brother who said this could fix it, which it indeed did. I only posted this in case other people who run into the same problem also have a hard time finding a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ultimately a result of Windows using the drives to cache some data so that it can start up faster. It can be fixed by changing some settings in windows.

Start by opening `cmd` as admin and execute `powercfg -H off` to turn off the hibernate feature. Next navigate to the power options in the system management and deactivate `fast startup` as well as the standby mode. When booting into linux, the drives should now behave normally.

Furthermore you might want to consider not using the regular windows shutdown, but rather doing a reboot when switching from windows to linux as @LinuxSecurityFreak explained in the comments.

Comment: Even if you turn off Fast startup, reboot from Windows and booting Linux is always best solution.

Comment: Further, it is untrue, that _Windows is not properly shutting down drives_, it's just using the system disk to start up faster next time.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by your first comment. You mean not shutting down windows via a regular shutdown but rather a reboot and then just cancelling this windows reboot and booting into linux? Why?

Comment: Reboot skips the fast startup feature and all possibly other prefetching mechanisms.

Comment: Interesting - but I'd rather not interrupt the reboot every time (I have to shut off completely so that I can swap drives)

Comment: Ok, just make it clearer in your answer then. Cheers!

Comment: I edited the answer, thanks!